# How to create a bold, red text label in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, text, richtext

I want to write a single, bold red line in my application using Qt.

As far as I understand, I would create a QLabel, set its textFormat to rich text and give it a rich text string to display:

```
QLabel *warning = new QLabel;
warning->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
warning->setText("{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252 {\\fonttbl\\f0\\fswiss\\fcharset0 Helvetica;} {\\colortbl;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;} \\f0 \\cf0 this is bold red text}");
```

I tested this rich text string in a rich text editor and it displays fine.

But Qt displays the whole string with all braces, keywords and backslashes instead of "this is bold red text". What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try using HTML formatting: `<b><font... etc </b>`.

Qt Designer does it like this: `<span style=" font-size:8pt; font-weight:600; color:#aa0000;">TextLabel</span>`

Comment: You may need to set the QLabel's textFormat attribute to Qt::RichText.

Comment: <b> and </b> shows as text and doesnt format when used on a QLabel

Answer (score 48):

You can use [Qt StyleSheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) and set the `styleSheet` property of `QLabel`

```
warning->setStyleSheet("font-weight: bold; color: red");
```

Qt supports most CSS styles on its `QWidget`-derived classes. You don't need to set the text format to `Qt::RichText` for this to work.

Comment: Answering my own comment: it is becouse first part(title) was in `font` tag with `size` set to relative value and other body wasn't in it...

Answer (score 13):

Qt uses a simple [HTML subset](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it programmatically using the `settext` function. Something like this:

```
QString labelText = "<P><b><i><font color='#ff0000' font_size=4>";
labelText .append("Text what u want to display");
labelText .append("</font></i></b></P></br>");
QLabel label->setText(labelText);
```

You can do it in a single line as well.