# Make one word in string a color in QT

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to make one word (filestatus) in a string a certain color.  What I have below does not produce an error but it does not work.  I am a beginner and am using a Qt UI.

```
filestatus = "MARRIED, JOINT"

self.ui.title.setText(str("My Tax Info Based on a Filing Status of:  " + filestatus.format("color=blue")))
```

Comment: Which version of PyQt is this?

Comment: 3.3 or 3.4 I think

Comment: Have a look at Qt doc. [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#details). You can set rich text (which allows coloring). There is an extra page for [Supported HTML Subset](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html).

Comment: QT designer 4.2.1

Comment: `ui.title`? I'm not sure whether this can be used in window title bars. (I'm rather sure you cannot but this may depend on the Window Manager in quest.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464591/how-to-create-a-bold-red-text-label-in-qt

Comment: The line appears in a label, not the title bar at top

Comment: `QLabel` supports rich text. You can use [`QLabel::setTextFormat`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#textFormat-prop) to make sure the label will interpret the string as rich text. See the supported subset [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys                             
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *                           
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        pngdir = 'Ok.png';
        filestatus = "MARRIED, JOINT"
        label = QLabel("""
                       <img src={} width=250><hr width=200 style='margin: 15px 0'>
                       My Tax Info Based on a Filing Status of: <b style="color: #0000FF;">{}</b> 
                       """.format(pngdir, filestatus));  

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]